# Migrate project service application from 2010 Farm to 2013

Tags: migration, project-server

I need to migrate a project service application hosted on a 2010 farm to a different farm wich is 2013. Any pointers on how I go about doin this?

Many thanks,

Luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To migrate a Project Service Application 2010 to 2013, I know only one supported method and that is `Database Attach Upgrade to 2013`.

To confirm this fact you can check this article where all the approach of migrating service applications is listed among which Project Service Application is also listed.

[Approaches to migrating your service applications](https://bramdejager.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/approaches-to-migrating-your-service-applications/)

The next article link can help you demonstrate how to perform a Project Server Database Attach Upgrade Process.

[Migrating PS 2010 to PS 2013 Walkthrough](http://epmsource.com/2013/05/02/migrating-ps-2010-to-ps-2013-walkthrough/)

Comment: Do I need to create a web application without associating content databases to start with? The latter document does not make any reference to that. What happens in my case is that the destination 2013 farm does not have a web application at the present time.

Comment: Yes you need to create one. Check this article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to Project Server 2013 from Project Server 2010 can be separated into the following sequential phases:

1. Create the Project Server 2013 farm
2. Copy the required databases from the Project Server 2010 farm
3. Restore the databases to the computer that is running SQL Server
   that is hosting your Project Server 2013 databases
4. Upgrade the databases
5. Upgrade the Project Web App site collection

Following the list of database which required for migration.

- Project Server 2010 Archive
- Project Server 2010 Draft
- Project Server 2010 Published
- Project Server 2010 Reporting
- SharePoint content database that contains the Project Web App site
  data

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662496.aspx

Also watch this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JI3yY70A54